# Wildfly 10 Memory Leak Issue

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, wildfly-10

I am using wildfly 10.0.0 Final version. I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error` whenever i undeploy/deploy modules 9-10 times also the memory usage of wildfly keeps on increasing slowly and never decreases and it again gives `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error.`

Wildfly is not releasing the memory after undeployment of application and keeps on increasing on deployment and thus it leads to GC overhead

Earlier when i was using wildfly 9 version it didnt gave that problem.

I tried the fix given in the below link by replacing the core, servlet and websocket modules with the latest release but it didnt worked for me.

```
https://developer.jboss.org/message/959286
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 27):

You have to increase your heap memory. For this

Edit `bin/standalone.conf` configuration file, look for the first occurrence of `JAVA_OPTS`.

Then change the `-Xmx` option as you need.

### If you use Java 8, then

Change:

```
JAVA_OPTS=”-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true”
```

To:

```
JAVA_OPTS=”-Xms64m -Xmx2G -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true”
```

### Resource Link:

[WildFly 10 — java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metadata space](https://gesker.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/wildfly-10-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-metadata-space/)

### UPDATE: [Classes not unloaded after undeployment](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6173)

### Martin kouba stated below

1. undeploy does not necessarily mean class unloading - it depends on
   JVM settings (-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize and friends for Java8)
2. I've verified that after 50 deploy/undeploy cycles of the attached
   reproducer (and using -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m):

> for WildFly 10.0.0.Final "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"
>   occurs
>
> for WildFly 10.1.0-SNAPSHOT (fix for [WFLY-6347](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6347) merged) no OOM
>   error occurs (metaspace is garbage collected)

After examining the heap dump I've identified the 
`org.jboss.el.cache.BeanPropertiesCache` as the root cause. In this case, it keeps a hard reference to the `person.joey.test.TestClientBean` class, thus effectively blocking the relevant ModuleClassLoader from GC.

Enum values are treated similarly to static constants - i.e. it's not garbage collected unless the class loader of the owner class is.

That's why `person.joey.test.RequestType` values remain in memory. OmniFaces only amplifies the impact - as mentioned above, it holds a reference to a BeanManager.

Comment: i have already done that but the problem is wildfly do not release the memory after undeployment and after redeployment it increases the memory usage and leads to gc overhead

Comment: I don't agree at all. It will just retard the OutOfMemoryError, that will appear after some deploys. Probably it's a bug... The only solution I know is restart Wildfly before deploy.

Comment: Still happening until today 2020